# MSBuild tools offline installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

I am trying to create MSBuild offline installation using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#step-3---install-visual-studio-from-the-local-cache).

I first downloaded [MSBuild tool 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=buildtools&rel=16&utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=offline%20install&utm_content=download%20vs2019)

Then I ran this command:

```
  vs_community.exe --layout c:\vslayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.Component.MSBuild --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreBuildTools 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler --add Microsoft.NetCore.BuildTools.ComponentGroup --add Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Core.Component.SDK.2.1 --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

I am confused now about what dependencies I must include to build .net 4.5 based windows and web application. I also need to build .core applications.

I was reading [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?vs-2019&view=vs-2019) which list multiple dependencies. Which one I must include? They have:

1. Azure development build tools
2. [Data storage and processing build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#data-storage-and-processing-build-tools)
3. [.NET desktop build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#net-desktop-build-tools)
4. [MSBuild Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#msbuild-tools)
5. [.NET Core build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#net-core-build-tools)
6. [Node.js build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#nodejs-build-tools)

   **I only need ability to build .net 4.5 windows and web apps (ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API, Console app) & .NET Core based application. Please suggest required dependencies. I think I need to include all dependenices listed in point 3, 4 & 5.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need:

- .NET Desktop Build Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools)
- .NET Core Build Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools)
- Web Development Build Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools)
- .NET Framework 4.5 Targeting Pack (Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack)

Answer (score 5):

with the help of Yaakov's answer this is what we did:

1. [Downloaded](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools) the build tools
2. Ran following command to create offline installation file.

   vs_BuildTools.exe --layout c:\vslayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools  --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack --includeOptional --lang en-US
3. This created a folder @  c:\vslayout . Which was about 1.2 GB in size.
4. Copy the folder on build machine.
5. Install certificates available @ `C:\vslayout\certificates` to **computer (not to user)**
6. run `C:\vslayout\vs_BuildTools.exe --noweb` command to install msbuild.

Comment: I believe this answer is out of date now; the installer errors out